# What is the /dev/shm equivalence in Windows System?

Tags: windows, linux, shared-memory, ramdisk, ramdrive

I was wondering how can I make the IO faster by writing and reading temporary files to main memory. I've used to write to /dev/shm in Linux.

But now I'm in Windows 7. Anyone knows the answer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood it correctly (based on [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html) post) what you are looking for is [Memory Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx).

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the accepted answer as the question was about an equivalence of `/dev/shm` for Windows (or at least that was my interpretation).  Is there shared ram based filesystem for Windows?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CreateFile() with FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY, and Windows should try to keep it in cache as much as possible.

Comment: What I wanted is a nonprogramming way. Just like writing regular files in specific directory.